# why I can't access my application inside my AndroidViewModel class?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I am new in Android development especially using MVVM pattern. I need context in my viewModel, so I use `AndroidViewModel` to get `context` through `application`, but I don't know why I can't access the application

```
class CreateEventViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    fun checkIfItHasInternetConnection() {

        if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(application)) {

        }

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: make your constructor parameter `private val`

Comment: Hey checkout my answer hope this may help you @Alexa

Comment: You forgot the `private val`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to call `getApplication<Application>()`. This is a method in AndroidViewModel to get the application :) No need to store application as a field.

Answer (score 0):

use private val application:Application in primary constructor

below example : 
try this way

```
class CreateEventViewModel(private val application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

fun checkIfItHasInternetConnection() {

    if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(application)) {

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class CreateEventViewModel(private val application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    fun checkIfItHasInternetConnection() {

        if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(application)) {

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

updated code:

```
data class CreateEventViewModel(val application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    fun checkIfItHasInternetConnection() {

        if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(application)) {

        }

    }

}
```